# How to update crud in php?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

My php crud (object oriented and pdo) update is not working. It shows

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. On $stmtExec = $stmt->execute();

I tried to change the variable and the arguments, parameters and spacing but, still got an invalid result. How can I fix this?

```
public function updateId($fields, $stud_id) {

    $st = "";
    $counter = 1;
    $total_fields = count($fields);

    foreach($fields as $key => $value){

        if($counter == $total_fields){

            $set = "$key = :".$key;
            $st = $st.$set;

        } else {

            $set = "$key = :".$key.", ";
            $st = $st.$set;
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    $sql = "";
    $sql.= "UPDATE students SET ".$st;
    $sql.= "WHERE id = ".$stud_id;
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

    foreach($fields as $key => $value){
        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
    }
    $stmtExec = $stmt->execute();

    //if successful
    if($stmtExec){
        header('Location: index.hp');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this update statement simpler and cleaner (in my opinion). Below is some code for present concept to you:

```
<?php

// data, where key is column name and value is value to set
$dataForUpdate = [
    'column1' => 'value for column 1',
    'column2' => 'value for column 2',
];

// identifier of object for update
$objectId = 2;

$updateString = 'UPDATE tableName SET ';
$updateColumnParts = [];
$valuesForUpdate = [];
foreach($dataForUpdate as $key => $value) {
    $updateColumnParts[] = "$key = ?";
    $valuesForUpdate[] = $value;
}

// add object id as lat parameter
$valuesForUpdate[] = $objectId;

// implode array of "SET x = ?" with "," sign - there is no need to additional counter to determine if you should add ' after SET part'
$updateString .= implode(',', $updateColumnParts);
$updateString .= ' WHERE id = ?';

$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

$result = $stmt->execute($valuesForUpdate);
```